# How do I point a docker image to my .m2 directory for running maven in docker on a mac?

Tags: linux, macos, maven, docker, vagrant

When you look at the [Dockerfile for a maven build](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/40cbcd2edc2719c64062af39baac6ae38d0becf9/jdk-7/Dockerfile) it contains the line:

```
VOLUME /root/.m2
```

Now this would be great if this is where my `.m2` repository was on my mac - but it isn't - it's in

```
/Users/myname/.m2
```

Now I could do:

But then the linux implementation in Docker wouldn't know to look there. I want to map the linux location to the mac location, and have that as part of my `vagrant init`. Kind of like:

```
ln /root/.m2 /Users/myname/.m2
```

My question is: **How do I point a docker image to my .m2 directory for running maven in docker on a mac?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How do I point a docker image to my .m2 directory for running maven in docker on a mac?

You rather point a host folder (like /Users/myname/.m2) to a *container* folder (not an image)

See "[Mount a host directory as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)":

> In addition to creating a volume using the `-v` flag you can also **mount a directory from your Docker daemon’s host into a container**.

```
$ docker run -d -P --name web -v /Users/myname/.m2:/root/.m2 training/webapp python app.py
```

> This command mounts the host directory, `/Users/myname/.m2`, into the container at `/root/.m2`.
>   If the path `/root/.m2` already exists inside the container’s image, the `/Users/myname/.m2` mount overlays but does not remove the pre-existing content.
>   Once the mount is removed, the content is accessible again.
>   This is consistent with the expected behavior of the mount command.

Comment: By some reasons this not working for me. In build stage maven still download dependencies... Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know more: what host OS,  image OS, maven version are you using? Could you detail those information in a new question?

Comment: It is just docker cant share volumes while build. Just in run, https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14080

Comment: Very confusing why you're mounting a Maven folder and running a Python script :) In any case, wouldn't this cause permissions issues when maven (eventually) downloads and writes files within the volume ***as its uid/gid***?)

Comment: @OneCricketeer like any mounted folder, you must make sure your image uses the right uid/gid if it intent to persist data in said mounted folder indeed.

Answer (score 9):

To share the .m2 folder in build step you can overwrite the localRepository value in settings.xml.

Here is the Dockerfile snippet I used to share my local .m2 repository in docker.

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 as BUILD

RUN echo \
    "<settings xmlns='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0\' \
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' \
    xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd'> \
        <localRepository>/root/Users/myname/.m2/repository</localRepository> \
        <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode> \
        <usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry> \
        <offline>false</offline> \
    </settings>" \
    > /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml;

COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN mvn --batch-mode -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:8-jre
EXPOSE 8080 5005
COPY --from=BUILD /usr/src/app/target /opt/target
WORKDIR /opt/target
ENV _JAVA_OPTIONS '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005'
ENV swarm.http.port 8080

CMD ["java", "-jar", "app-swarm.jar"]
```

Comment: You must still be mounting a volume here to make `/root/Users/myname/` work within the container? You also don't need a "target" folder for a JAR to be ran

Answer (score 2):

Here are the Dockerfiles and docker-compose for example project containing one spring service and any other services;

Spring-service dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8-alpine 

WORKDIR /app

COPY . src

CMD cd src ; mvn spring-boot:run
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  account-service:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "${HOME}/.m2:/root/.m2"
```

Here in docker-compose we make volumes for our local .m2 repo and container one.

Comment: You should consider not using `mvn` to run the app. The JDK isn't needed, and this causes larger image sizes

Answer (score 0):

I am using `maven:3-amazoncorretto-17` as my base image.

Using some info from [Arun A's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52506686/1289016) answer I was able to come up with a pretty simple solution. The tricky part (for me) was figuring out where the settings.xml needed to go inside the container. Also, this example is mounting just `settings.xml`.

Using `docker-compose`:

```
    volumes:
      - "~/.m2/settings.xml:/usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml"
```

Or `docker run -v`

```
$ docker run -v ~/.m2/settings.xml:/usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml maven:3-amazoncorretto-17
```

This syntax should work on both Windows and Mac.