# How to Register Applications in Spring Cloud DataFlow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm starting with **Spring Cloud DataFlow**, I've run an instance through **Docker Compose** and successfully created *Streams* with samples apps.

I've written a **Source** and a **Sink** app on my own and I'm not able to register them into the **SCDF** dashboard.

[image]

I've tried both the `maven://` and the `file:///` addresses, but since the dashboard runs inside a **Docker** container, I guess the problem is that it can't access to local .m2 repository nor to the local file system where the jars are located.

**How should I proceed? Should I map the file system through Docker Compose or what?**

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. We haven't explored this option yet, but I have [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#2286](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2286), and we will look into it soon. In the meantime, maybe you could explore the option described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234088/how-do-i-point-a-docker-image-to-my-m2-directory-for-running-maven-in-docker-on). Possibly also contribute it back to the project, if you're successful with it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete and official answer from the dataflow documentation: [Accessing the Host File System](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/#accessing-the-host-file-system)

Note that the you need to mount **exactly** the same volume to both `dataflow-server`:

```
dataflow-server:
  # ...
  volumes:
     - /home/MY_USER_NAME/.m2:/home/cnb/.m2
```

and the `skipper-server`:

```
skipper-server:
  # ...
  volumes:
     - /home/MY_USER_NAME/.m2:/home/cnb/.m2
```

> **Note:** Starting with DataFlow 2.8.0+ and Skipper 2.7.1+ the in-container mount paths had changed from `/root/.m2` to `/home/cnb/.m2/`
> instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was precisely that.

I'm reporting **@SabbyAnandan** comment here (comments have no history, and this is a meaningful one)

> Thanks for reporting this. We haven't explored this option yet, but I have [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow#2286](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2286), and we will look into it soon.
>
> In the meantime, maybe you could explore the option described in this
> [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234088/how-do-i-point-a-docker-image-to-my-m2-directory-for-running-maven-in-docker-on).
> Possibly also contribute it back to the project, if you're successful
> with it. :)

While waiting for an automated solution, for now it's enough to add the following line to the `docker-compose.yml`:

```yml
# ... stuff ...
dataflow-server:
# ... stuff ....
  volumes:
    - /home/MY_USER_NAME/.m2:/root/.m2
```

This way we'll be able to load our artifacts through UI in the Maven form:

```
maven://com.foo.bar:my-source:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

(assuming that we've run `mvn clean install` to install the artifact on the .m2 repository of the *same* system where Docker-Compose is running, which is not necessarily our, but potentially a remote one).

Comment: This answer is incomplete, as the skipper-server needs access to the same volume. E.g. you need to mount Exactly the same volume to both the dataflow-server and the skipper-server as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60113245/4430769

Comment: Thank you for the update @tzolov, I've now accepted your answer