# Embed .m2 folder to docker image to create a base image

Tags: java, maven, docker, dockerfile

I am in the process of creating a docker image where I can use for my project as a base image with inbuilt maven .m2 folder. I can mount my host .m2 to container .m2 but its not what I am looking for. How can I build a docker image with a .m2 (according to a specific pom) embed in to it.

Comment: What do you want to have in this folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I point a docker image to my .m2 directory for running maven in docker on a mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234088/how-do-i-point-a-docker-image-to-my-m2-directory-for-running-maven-in-docker-on)