# Include local Maven m2 repo in Dockerfile during mvn package stage?

Tags: java, maven, docker

How can I include the local machine `~/.m2/repository` in the `mvn dependency:resolve` stage of `docker build`? There is no `-v` option for `docker build`. Is this possible with just `docker build` to be compatible with our existing build pipeline (only a solitary Dockerfile is allowed)? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234088/how-do-i-point-a-docker-image-to-my-m2-directory-for-running-maven-in-docker-on) didn't help.

Current Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.2-jdk-11 AS maven

WORKDIR /tmp/

# Set the local repository to /tmp/.m2/repository
RUN echo \
    "<settings xmlns='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0\' \
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' \
    xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd'> \
        <localRepository>/tmp/.m2/repository</localRepository> \
        <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode> \
        <usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry> \
        <offline>false</offline> \
    </settings>" \
    > /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml;

# TODO: How to perform -v ~/.m2/:/tmp/.m2/ but only using `docker build`?

COPY pom.xml /tmp/
RUN mvn dependency:resolve
RUN mvn dependency:resolve-plugins

COPY src /tmp/src/
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install curl

WORKDIR /usr/app

ENV TARGET="<target name>.jar"

COPY --from=maven "/tmp/target/$TARGET" .
CMD ["java", "-jar", "$TARGET"]
```

And of course this doesn't work:

[image: Failed copy]

Update: I'm able to mount a folder pointing to the local .m2 repo and copy the whole folder into the docker image. However, now I cannot make `mvn` use that local repo.

[image: able to copy local repo]

Then

```
COPY pom.xml /tmp/
RUN mvn -o -s /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml dependency:resolve -X
```

results in the error:

```
Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact com.myapp:somename:pom:1.0.4 has not been downloaded from it before.
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea, that you can do is caching the maven dependencies in the docker. You can make use of **mvn dependency-offline** (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/), doing the dependency-offline maven resolve the dependencies needed in preparation for going offline and reuse them as long as the pom.xml still be the same