# Maven build through Jenkins pipeline takes 4 times longer than usual

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Our Jenkins pipeline has a stage to build with following command -

```
mvn clean install -DdestFolder=<destination-folder-path>
```

Above command takes 1 hour when run through pipeline. If same is run locally from same machine, it takes only 15 mins.

When run through Jenkins pipeline, I can see enough memory, enough space. Also I had explicitly assigned memory to maven using MAVEN_OPTS, still same result.

Could you please help to understand what could be wrong here?

Comment: So, does every part of the build take longer, or is there one part that sticks out?

Comment: When you build the project with maven , it cache the dependency on ~/.m2 and it reused when you run second time - Thats the reason it fast on your local machine. 
But you do the same in Jenkins and If your Jenkins has many agents , it has to cache the artifact in that many agents, because you never know when Jenkins schedules your build in which agent. 
If you share your piepline details and Jenkins structure i might give you an example , How to cache is a specific folder and reuse that for each build

Comment: Can you give some numbers like how many classes / lines of code you are compiling? How many tests are running ? The time the test take?

Comment: How long does it take if you remove local Maven repository from the "same machine"? Is it closer to 15 minutes or to 1 hour?

Comment: @JFabianMeier, there are multiple modules and each module takes longer. One more point which I observed is - when build is run in docker container it takes longer time and when run directly on host, it takes lesser time, which I'll add in the question or will report another question.

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel, in the past same pipeline build has run  multiple times on those agents which are dedicated for that pipeline and we never cleanup .m2 hence there are always some dependencies always downloaded.

Comment: @IllyaKysil, if I clean up .m2 then it takes one hour.

Comment: So the problem is the missing local repository?

Comment: @JFabianMeier, i.e. you are suspecting that instead of picking up dependencies from .m2, build is downloading them from remote repository?

Comment: Maybe your Jenkins pipeline always uses a fresh local repository.

Comment: Thanks @JFabianMeier, your this guidance helped me to resolve this issue. With my docker container args in pipeline, I had code for host to container mapping : -v $HOME/.m2:/usr/share/.m2 and which was somehow downloading artifacts everytime. But when I changed it to root's path (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52506686/1471417) like - $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2 and which correctly refers to host's m2 repo and avoid re-downloading of downloaded artifacts. Maybe I should answer this to help others.